# app engine big table

Tags: google-app-engine, bigtable

what is bigtable. Is any authentication require to create table in bigtable.where the data will be store. it is possible to view the table. we can view all the tables in bigtable, which was created by others.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take your several questions one at a time:
[Bigtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) is the system on which AppEngine's datastore is built. It is effectively a distributed hashtable.

Authentication is required in that you must have a Google Account; you must have signed up for AppEngine; you must have created an application within AppEngine. You application will be able to access the datastore, and if you are logged in to your application's Admin Console, you can use the Datastore Viewer to inspect the contents of your application's datastore.

The data will be stored on Google Servers.

There are no tables, per se, but you can use the Datastore Viewer to view entities that reside in your application's Datastore.

No, you can not ever view the Datastore's contents that were created by other applications. Each application's view of the Datastore is completely siloed and has no connection to that of other AppEngine applications.